# li indentation not going away

Tags: html, html-lists, margin, padding

Forgive me if this is incredibly basic, but after researching online for a few minutes, I can't find how to remove the natural indentation from an HTML list. Here is what I have tried with the CSS:

(check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QxAVv/))

CSS

```
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>There</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>still</li>
    <li>an</li>
    <li>indent</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

Comment: You need to reset the stylesheet http://jsfiddle.net/QxAVv/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most browsers, a `ul` has a `padding-left` of `40px` to allocate spacing for the bullet points.

Simply overwrite the padding. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jG4Mh/)

```
ul {
   padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that the code of mr.musicman is right. Just remove `li` and keep `ul`, it'll work fine

Comment: @Vinh That is incorrect syntax though. `li` elements cannot exist without a parent `ul` or `ol`.

Comment: Yes, and `ul { padding:0; }` is enough to do it. I just say that if he remove `li` in his code, it'll work too :)